# Apache VirtualHost - domain name

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I bought a domain name, one with ".fr" and the other one with ".com"

Now I want to redirect my domaine name to a server running on the port 4000.

For that I used virualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://www.example.fr
ServerAlias example.fr
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia On

ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/

ErrorLog logs/error_log
CustomLog logs/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine when I access ".com" but doesn't work with the ".fr".

Any idea ? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ServerName and ServerAlias to:

```
ServerName example.fr
ServerAlias www.example.fr example.com www.example.com
```